# SQL Query for Data Comparison between Tables

Tags: sql, comparison

I am newbie to SQL query. I have got a requirement to compare data between 2 different tables and provide the mismatch of the destination table comparing it against the Source table. Let me specify it more clearly with an example.

Source is considered as 'Table1' in 'ServerX'
Destination is considered as 'Table2' in 'ServerY'
Both these 2 tables have different ColumnNames containing the same data like 'Street Address' (in 'Table1') vs 'Living Place' (in 'Table2') for Employees
Each table may different information stored in both these tables for Employees like 'Table1' can have 'Salary' as an Column; whereas 'Table2' might not have that information
We are expected to compare the data that is present in 'Table1' with 'Table2' for each employee record and get the differentials that doesn't match the source
Both these tables have 'Employee ID' as common in both of them

I understand that there are multiple tools available online to get this done, but we are in need to build a SQL query to get this done.

Thanks in advance for all your suggestions.

Comment: Well, what platform is this for?  What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Use a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE CONCAT(col1, col2) NOT IN (SELECT CONCAT(col1, col2) FROM table2)
```

It will be real slow on very large tables,
but I think its the SQL that you're looking for.